# Unable to Render Empty(null) column inside Grid in Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs4, extjs4.2, extjs5

I'm using Extjs for rendering some information inside grid. Columns properties are like:

```
SEValue: {
        dataIndex: "SEValue",
        header: MCW.lr.s_lbl_sevalue,
        hidden: false,
        renderer: MCW.common.DeviceHelper.renderSEValue,
        infoGroup: 30
    },
```

Below method is used for manipulation of rendered values:

```
MCW.common.DeviceHelper.renderSEValue = function (value) {
    if (value) return value;
   return "Not Available";
};
```

Problem is that, whenever column value is '' or Null in DB, it doesn't show that column and in case of any value it shows the column.

Answer (score 0):

M.b. need in field `dataIndex: "SEValue",` from which to draw the column's value set `allowNull = true`?